# Cannot delete AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't delete my AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application. The errors are as in the screenshot below:

[image]
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in the screenshot shows that Elastic BeanStalk cannot find the RDS instance.
This is because you might have deleted the RDS instance manually.
Create an instance with the same DB instance name and try deleting the environment.

Thanks

Comment: YES you have to create a new RDS instance with the same name. NOTE 1: you have to disable secure deletion from db option. NOTE 2: this delete the db instance too.

Answer (score 0):

please fix the url of error screenshot. (you can add ss to post)